# Reformatting csv file

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have a csv file that has the following format:

```
Line,Title1,Title2,Title3,Title4,Title5
181,25.1,225.2,-7,120.3,35
180,10.1,325.2,-5,320.3,20
179,0.1,525.2,-2,520.3,0
178,0.1,525.3,-2,520.5,0
177,0.1,525.3,-2,520.6,0
```

I would like to format it to the following structure:

```
Line;Title;Value
181,Title1,25.1
181,Title2,225.2
181,Title3,-7
181,Title4,120.3
181,Title5,35
182,Title1,10.1
182,Title2,325.2
182,Title3,-5
182,Title4,320.3
182,Title5,20
```

Till this far I have imported the csv into a datatable with the following function:

```
Public Function CsvToDatatable(ByVal filename As String, ByVal separator As String)
    'Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
    'Dim firstLine As Boolean = True
    Dim myDate As DateTime

    If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        Using sr As New StreamReader(filename)
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                If firstLine Then
                    firstLine = False
                    Dim cols = sr.ReadLine.Split(separator)
                    For Each col In cols
                        If col <> "Title" Then
                            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(col, GetType(Decimal)))
                        Else
                            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(col, GetType(String)))
                        End If

                    Next
                Else
                    Dim data() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(separator)
                    'Dim oDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(data(0))
                    'data(0) = oDate
                    dt.Rows.Add(data.ToArray) 
                End If
            End While
        End Using
    End If
    Return dt
End Function
```

My idea is to transform the datatable to the new format via another function. But I don't know how to do this.
What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? You should be posting questions here once you've exhausted your own ingenuity.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write the output CSV as you go instead of loading it into a DataTable. The following code achieves that:

```
Public Sub ConvertCsv(sourceFile As String, destinationFile As String, delimiter As String)

    If IO.File.Exists(sourceFile) Then

        Dim reader As New StreamReader(sourceFile)
        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(destinationFile)

        Dim headers As String()

        If Not reader.EndOfStream Then

            ' Read headers
            headers = reader.ReadLine.Split(delimiter)

            While Not reader.EndOfStream

                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
                Dim values = Split(line, delimiter)
                Dim item As String

                ' Save first column as the item name
                item = values(0)

                ' Loop through remaining columns
                For counter As Integer = 1 To values.Count - 1

                    ' Write line with values to destination file
                    writer.WriteLine(item & delimiter & headers(counter) & delimiter & values(counter))

                Next

            End While

        End If

        ' CLose files
        reader.Close()
        writer.Close()

    End If

End Sub
```